# Tomcat Embedded Project Works in Eclipse But Fails As Runnable Jar

Tags: tomcat, executable-jar

The goal is a webapp in a standalone executable jar that incorporates Tomcat Embedded.
It builds and runs perfectly without any issues in Eclipse. Then, after exporting the project as a 'Runnable Jar' file and attempting to run it from cmd console with java -jar filename.jar it fails, with many errors.

It's only one file. Here is **the code:**

```java
package test.example.tomcat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // URL in browser would be:
        // localhost:8080/tce/
         try {
            new Main().start();
        } catch (MalformedURLException | ServletException | LifecycleException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: Setting up Tomcat failed.\n"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void start() throws ServletException, LifecycleException, MalformedURLException {

    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    // set port
    String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8080";
    }
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

    // detrmine webapp local path
    String webappDirLocation = "WebContent/";
    // detrmine context path
    String contextPath = "/tce";
    // detrmine base directory for files
    String docBase = new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath();
    // detrmine servlet name
    String servletName = "TcEEx";
    // detrmine root url path
    String urlPattern = "/";

    // create a very basic servlet
    HttpServlet servlet = new HttpServlet() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            System.out.println("Gooooooooooooooooood Morning!");                
        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

            writer.println("<html><title>Welcome</title><body>");
            writer.println("<h1>Have a Great Day!</h1>");
            writer.println("</body></html>");
        }
    };

    // set server base directory
    tomcat.setBaseDir(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    // instantiate context
    Context ctx = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, docBase);
    // add regular servlet
    tomcat.addServlet(contextPath, servletName, servlet);
    // map servlet
    ctx.addServletMappingDecoded(urlPattern, servletName);
    // get the default HTTP connector
    tomcat.getConnector();

    // start server
    try {
        tomcat.start();
    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Starting Tomcat failed."+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    tomcat.getServer().await();
    }

}
```

**console output:**

```
Feb 17, 2019 10:53:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 17, 2019 10:53:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Feb 17, 2019 10:53:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
Feb 17, 2019 10:53:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@4fb64261]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455)
        at test.example.tomcat.Main.start(Main.java:98)
        at test.example.tomcat.Main.main(Main.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@4fb64261]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4783)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4918)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
        at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:699)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:682)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 32 more

Feb 17, 2019 10:53:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455)
        at test.example.tomcat.Main.start(Main.java:98)
        at test.example.tomcat.Main.main(Main.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@4fb64261]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@4fb64261]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4783)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4918)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
        at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:699)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:682)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 32 more

Error: Starting Tomcat failed.A child container failed during start
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455)
        at test.example.tomcat.Main.start(Main.java:98)
        at test.example.tomcat.Main.main(Main.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@4fb64261]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@4fb64261]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4783)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4918)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
        at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:699)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:682)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        ... 32 more
```

relevant **details:**

- Apache Tomcat 9.0.16 Embedded
- Tomcat's jars are in Classpath (Java Build Path)
- Eclipse Oxygen.3a 4.7.3a
- Webapp created as a Dynamic Web Project
- Not using maven/gradle etc and no framework such as Spring. Doing it manually.
- Java 1.8.201
- Win7/x64

After research of similar questions on stackoverflow/google and their suggestions/answers, here are some of the **reconciliation attempts that failed** (or ruled out) to solve this problem:

- Clean/Rebuild project before exporting..
- Verified Tomcat jars were included in my jar.
- Made sure the port is free.
- Re-downloading Jars
- Trying each of the three library handling options in Eclipse executable jar dialogue
- Recreating project as a Java Project instead of a Dynamic Web Application (this actually made the project not run in Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

Alright solved it by my own so I'll keep this question posted and answer it myself because this is quite a minimal and nice code example for a working Webapp with the latest, as of now, Tomcat embedded that can easily be packed into a self contained and executable jar and all that without any 3rd party jar/fat jar packing tools or package automation tools. I WISH someone had left this post with this solution for me. Would have saved so much time and effort.

So here's what's wrong:
**step one**
As can be seen in the console output in the original question, there are some collisions between classes and methods. This had happened because the wrong option was selected when the project was exported by Eclipse into a runnable jar file.
There are 3 options:

- Extract required libraries into generated JAR
- Package required libraries into generated JAR
- Copy required libraries into a sub folder next to the generated JAR

The second was chosen but then those collisions happen. When choosing the first options these collisions don't happen.

**step two**
But then it still fails to run because of missing WebContent directory that is expected to be in the same path as the jar. So the quick solution, just to prove that it works with the directory there (of course not for production), is to create it when the program first launches with
new File("./WebContent").mkdirs();
e.g. in the main method or anywhere before its used.

**edit**
The only caveat is, since this option extracts the dependency jars and repacks them with the original, dependency jars of the same vendor+project, have  the same domain and will mix, which also can cause file name collisions in the future when adding many jars. So I'm **still open to someone with a better answer** that doesn't involve too much reliance on 3rd party tools. It would be nice if the main jar can hold the other dependencies as jars instead of extracted. Another way that wouldn't allow the dependency files to mix despite cases of same paths would also be nice.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue right now. Running the Jar-file from the terminal works perfectly fine and i can start the server. Now, I have a standalone E4-Eclipse application and try to start the Jar-file from the LifeCycleManager-class. It failed with the same error. What's exactly the problem here? Have you got a better explanation yet?